# WinError2 genericpath.py error while debugging?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am trying to debug my Python code in Visual Studio Code. It skips all my breakpoints and finds an error in genericpath.py.

Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Users\mlongtin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip'
File "C:\Users\mlongtin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
os.stat(path)
File "C:\Users\mlongtin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\mlongtin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Users\mlongtin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip'

I have tried restarting Visual Studio and the debugger, but nothing is working. This is my launch.json file:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false
    }
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Why did you have `python39.zip`.

I think you did not decompress when installing Python.

Download python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and reinstall python may solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same issue and found my solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10391

> With justMyCode: false and Raised Exceptions ticked , this is expected
> behavior. Debugger is stopping at points in library code where ever
> exceptions are raised. Note that runpy is in pyhton standard library
> and it raises FileNotFoundError while trying to find the right module
> or file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35241425)